# Octopus tentacle not connecting to Octopus server in polling mode

Tags: polling, octopus-deploy

I’m changing Octopus Tentacle Server to a windows 2016 server using Polling mode (same as on the current server).
However, I keep getting this exception below during the Tentacle setup on the server after providing the username and password. What am I doing wrong?

— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Octopus.Client.OctopusAsyncClient.d__14.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Octopus.Manager.Tentacle.TentacleConfiguration.SetupWizard.TentacleSetupWizardModel.d__198.MoveNext() in C:\buildAgent\work\e5cfddd118f4e691\source\Octopus.Manager.Tentacle\TentacleConfiguration\SetupWizard\TentacleSetupWizardModel.cs:line 563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for an error at this point is the server you are installing the Tentacle on does not have a route to the Octopus Server endpoint.
Ensure that you can browse to the Octopus UI from this server and that there are no proxies required to connect.

Also, ensure that your credentials are correct, but if the server is accessible, the message should tell you that you have incorrect credentials.